# SQL - copy data within same table and increment version

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert, ssis

I use **MS SQL** in combination with **SSIS** where I need to copy and paste rows of a table (**same** table for source and destination) for a given DocumentID while also *incrementing* the "subversion" column.

**Example:**

```
DocumentID=123 | Location=a | Version=2 |Subversion=4
DocumentID=123 | Location=b | Version=2 |Subversion=4
DocumentID=123 | Location=c | Version=2 |Subversion=4
```

**after copy:**

```
DocumentID=123 | Location=a | Version=2 |Subversion=5
DocumentID=123 | Location=b | Version=2 |Subversion=5
DocumentID=123 | Location=c | Version=2 |Subversion=5
```

Within SSIS I already increment the max(Subversion) (from 4 to 5 in the example).
What I need is a select/insert statement to copy the data.

Since this table has around 150 columns I was hoping for a way without listing all columns but I couldn't find any information if that is even possible.

I've tried Insert into in combination with Select but it always ended in errors (aggregate issues).

```
  Insert Into MyTable (AllMyColumns)
  select (AllmyColumns)
  from MyTable
  where DocumentID =123 AND ...
```

How do I need to build this statement?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Post your current statement. Why are you using SSIS for this? Should be possible with plain SQL query as the source and destination are the same table

Comment: Explaining the whole project isn't subject of my question :-)

Comment: Fine. Good luck getting an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think following workaround will help you.

```
--Move incremental rows to the #temp table
Select * into #temp from MyTable where DocumentID=123 and ......

Declare @version varchar(20)

Select @version = Max(SubVersion) from #temp

--To increment the value
set @version='Subversion='+Cast(Substring(@version,charindex('=',@version)+1,len(@version)) as int)+1

--To update the value into temp
update #temp set SubVersion=@version

--Now insert into your table
insert into MyTable
Select * from #temp

--drop the temp table
drop table #temp
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you need `insert into select` give this a try then, and add conditions as your desire..

```
INSERT INTO table1(docid, location, version, subversion)
SELECT  (docid, location, version, subversion)
FROM    table1
;
```

To give a better answer, you may need to at least show your current query and what mechanism makes the increment, table schema... I could even assume you are already at this step anyway...

Answer (score 1):

If your source and destination columns are in the sames order then just do:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE DocumentID =123 AND ...
```