# SQL - Insert into

Tags: sql-server

I would like to copy a row from a table into itself (but with a different ID).

I tried the following code and didn't work:

```
insert into myTable
select * from myTable where id='1'
```

Assuming my table looks like

```
id   | name    | age
-----------------------
 1   | tom     | 25
 2   | dick    | 35
 3   | harry   | 45
```

I'd like to copy the `tom` row and add it with a new ID:

```
id   | name    | age
-----------------------
 1   | tom     | 25
 2   | dick    | 35
 3   | harry   | 45
 4   | tom     | 25
```

Comment: you question is not clear at all

Comment: Do you want to duplicate some of the records in `myTable`? What is the error message?

Comment: Yeah. Suggestions? Two. First, learn how to make a proper error report. Second, try learning some basic SQL. And third, obviously - sorry, three - learn basic debugging techniques.

Comment: Well, apparently TomTom doesn't found it very clear and maybe it's a little bit difficult to express what i want in english, according to the fact isn't my main language. After all, this is a website where you ask in order to learn what you don't know, so you don't have to express your frustration in public.

Thanks @NishanthiGrashia for your answer!

Comment: @AfrasineiCodrin edited it for you, and nominated for re-open. I hope I understood it correctly :P

Comment: Ty @Joe, it's exactly what I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below Query: (Based on Original Question)

```
INSERT INTO myTable(field1, field2, field3)
SELECT  (field1, field2, field3)
FROM    myTable where field1='value1'
;
```

Refer [Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/15028) :

---

For your edited question, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14496838/3492139) answer might help.